# ImpulseSV's villager breeder not working in 1.16.1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built [ImpulseSV's villager breeder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTseLpa9Iyc) (without the farmer so I just manually feed them) and it worked in 1.15.2. But since I updated my world to 1.16.1, it doesn't work anymore. I even let the villagers free and replaced them with new ones but nothing happened. And when I say nothing, I mean nothing at all - no heart particles, no cloud particles - except when they pick up food they immediately throw most of them away.
Does anybody have the same issue? What could the problem be?

[image]

Comment: I heard of a bunch of iron farms breaking in 1.16. I also heard that the villagers must have worked recently for some actions (like breeding or making golems), but others have said that it's not true. What I do know for sure if that putting 16 beds, 16 workstations and a bell into a room and breeding villagers until there were 16 there made the iron farm work, so I stopped experimenting after that.